# Why are the signatures of these two methods different?

Tags: f#

Why do Bind1 and Bind2 have different signatures?

```
type T() =
  let bind(v, f) = v
  member self.Bind1 = bind
  member self.Bind2(a, b) = bind(a, b)
```

fsi reports them as

```
type T =
  class
    new : unit -> T
    member Bind2 : a:'a * b:'b -> 'a
    member Bind1 : (obj * obj -> obj)
  end
```

This came up when I was playing with some computation expressions and couldn't figure out why I was getting an error message about Bind not being defined.  Bind1-style didn't work, Bind2 did, and I couldn't figure out why.

Given the same objects, they do return the same result:

```
> q.Bind1(1:>obj,3:>obj);;
val it : obj = 1
> q.Bind2(1:>obj,3:>obj);;
val it : obj = 1
>
```

Using Microsoft F# Interactive, (c) Microsoft Corporation, All Rights Reserved
F# Version 1.9.7.4, compiling for .NET Framework Version v4.0.21006

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bind1 is a get property that returns a function while bind2 is a function.  You can see the get accessor if you evaluate bind1 and bind2 from an instance.

```
> let t = new T();;
val t : T
> t.Bind1;;
val it : (obj * obj -> obj) = <fun:get_Bind1@3>
> t.Bind2;;
val it : ('a * 'b -> 'a) = <fun:it@10>
```

You wrote the shorthand of

```
member self.Bind1
   with get() = bind
```

Using [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) you can see in Bind1 where obj comes from and the function object.

```
internal class get_Bind1@7 : FSharpFunc<Tuple<object, object>, object>
{
    // Fields
    public T self;

    // Methods
    internal get_Bind1@7(T self)
    {
        this.self = self;
    }

    public override object Invoke(Tuple<object, object> tupledArg)
    {
        object v = tupledArg.get_Item1();
        object f = tupledArg.get_Item2();
        return this.self.bind<object, object>(v, f);
    }
}
```

Along with what kvb said you can add type annotation to the class to avoid the generic objects.

```
type T<'a, 'b>() =
  let bind(v:'a, f:'b) = (v:'a)
  member self.Bind1 = bind
  member self.Bind2(a, b) = bind(a, b)

type T<'a,'b> =
  class
    new : unit -> T<'a,'b>
    member Bind2 : a:'a * b:'b -> 'a
    member Bind1 : ('a * 'b -> 'a)
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Erik's answer, because it is impossible to have generic properties on .NET objects, F# has to pick non-generic types for `v` and `f`, which default to `obj`.  You could choose other specific types and use a type annotation to give `Bind1` a different (but still non-generic) signature.